# Tomcat unable to locate desired keystore by Daemon Service Manager

Tags: java, tomcat, keystore

Currently I'm using java code to load KeyStore through .cmd by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute `java -jar main.jar`

The Code

```
this.ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
this.ks.load(null, null);
```

The program is able to load x509 Certificate by using the `startup.bat`  provided by Tomcat by default. (running in Administrator Account)

This **is not working** using **Daemon Service Manager** to start Tomcat, the KeyStore always returns empty.

I also tried using different accounts, but sadly same result: Empty KeyStore

[image: Account Settings Sample]

I already loaded the private key and all needed certificates to Local Computer / Current User.

How can I make this work?

Comment: The Windows certstore/keystore (at least for additions) is per userid. You need to either load to your userid and then (have svcmgr) run Tomcat under your userid, or load the key&cert in mmc to the userid you have svcmgr run it under.

Comment: Thank you. You point me to the right direction. I loaded the certificates by using command tools PsExec.exe -s cmd. Now the service account can find the cert. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the services account didn't have the key loaded.

Using Microsoft MMC won't work, as this will not run as services account and the key only loaded to users' store.

Use tools like **PsExec.exe** to load the key by commands.